# Recursively scanning the directory for the files

Tags: c++, boost, boost-filesystem

I am trying to iterate over the directory and print the name of all the files starting from the root.

Here's the short snippet I have written using `Boost::Filesystem` (1.52.0) in my program.

```
void testApp::getNames(const string& dirPath, string& fileExtension)
{
    namespace fs = boost::filesystem;
    namespace sys = boost::system;
    fs::path filePath(dirPath);
    for(fs::recursive_directory_iterator dir(filePath), dir_end; dir!=dir_end ;++dir)
    {
        cout<<*dir;
    }
}
```

On trying the compile this, strangely I am getting build errors which points `path.hpp` file on the following snippet:

```
    static const codecvt_type& codecvt()
    {
      return *wchar_t_codecvt_facet();
    }
```

The error that I get is `undefined reference to boost::filesystem3::path::wchar_t_codecvt_facet()'|`

I am on Ubuntu 12.10 using Codeblocks IDE for my project.

Comment: This is a linker-error - the file-system library has components that must be compiled and linked - it is not a header-only library.

Comment: Can you point to the linker flag that has to be used/

Comment: Isn't just to add -lboost_filesystem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a linker error. You need to link with the Boost filesystem library.

In the IDE, there should be a setting for adding libraries somewhere in the project settings. (I don't know exactly where, since I've never used Codeblocks.)

Comment: I am already using the following linker flag in my makefile `USER_LDFLAGS = -lboost_system` . Is the Boost::Filesytem linker different?

Comment: @user1240679 Yes, you need the `boost_filesystem` library, so add `-lboost_filesystem` to your `USER_LDFLAGS` variable.

Comment: Phew! Banged my head so much on this thing and it turned out to be linker flag only. Thanks